# how to remove special chars like this █ from string in php

Tags: php, preg-replace, special-characters

how to remove only this type of special chars ░▒▓█► from a string in php
I use this `preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xC0]/u', '',$string);`

but i want to allow special char like à,â, ', ", for french language

Comment: What characters do you want to preserve? (this way is probably more simple.)

Comment: i want to preserve french spécial characters :
`’, ‘,“, ”, «,», ‹, ›, —, æ, œ, €, ., ', ",@,À,Á,Â,Ã,Ä,Å,Ç,È,É,Ê,Ë,Ì,Í,Î,Ï,Ò,Ó,Ô,Õ,Ö,Ù,Ú,Û,Ü,Ý,à,á,â,ã,ä,å,ç,è,é,ê,ë,ì,í,î,ï,ð,ò,ó,ô,õ,ö,ù,ú,û,ü,ý,ÿ`

Comment: So spaces and digits are not allowed, nor `? ! : ; -` ? You should be precise (but no need to write characters one by one, just describe the characters categories)

Comment: yes spaces, digits, ponctuation are allowed, it for cleaning submitted content from pseudo artistic author `▆▆▆▆▆▆▆▆▆▆▆▆▆▆▆▆▆

►►► Lorem ipsum ►►►`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use unicode character classes like `\p{Latin}` for latin script, `\p{Sc}` for currency, `\p{P}` (or shorter `\pP`) for punctuation characters:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^0-9\p{Latin}\pP\p{Sc}@\s]+/u', '', $str);
```

You can find the different unicode character classes available in PCRE [here](http://pcre.org/original/pcre.txt). (search the sentence: *"The following general category property codes are supported"*)

Answer (score 3):

So, you want use the code point of UTF-8 but you want use the character encoding scheme of [ISO 8859-15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15). I think you can do it converting the string twice:

```
$text = iconv("ISO-8859-15", "UTF-8", iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-15//IGNORE", $text));
echo $text;
```